# 500.19 Error In Web Garden Mode Only

Tags: iis-7.5, web-garden

My ASP.NET web app runs fine under IIS 7.5.  But I want to make sure it's ready to run in a web farm.  So I enabled web garden on my dev machine.  (Set Maximum Worker Processes=2 in the app pool.)

Clicking around the site seems to go okay, but upon any AJAX request, I get 500.19 errors.  The error is like:

> The requested page cannot be accessed
>   because the related configuration data
>   for the page is invalid.
>
> Cannot add
>   duplicate collection entry of type
>   'error' with combined key attributes
>   'statusCode, subStatusCode'
>   respectively set to '404, -1'

In my web config, I have this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors>
    <error statusCode="404" path="Home/NotFound" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Looks fine to me, and I guess need it.  But for fun I removed the httpErrors section.  Then I get:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Of course I looked at MS's [troubleshooting 500.19 errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx).  But I'm guessing the error is a red herring.  The problem has something to do with my app pool or my code or something other than what the message is telling me.  As I said, everything runs beautifully with 1 Max Worker Process.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I have realized that the second error I mentionend, "Unable to connect to the remote server," was a real error caused by my application.  So the <error> element in web.config was the cause of the 500.19 error (which masked the real error).  And maybe I don't need this element because I have a similar element in system.web that seems to have the desired affect by itself.

Problem solved. However, I still wonder why there's no problem in single worker mode, and it breaks in web garden mode?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of this error?

Comment: When you tried this, were you attempting to debug in visual studio or run the site directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `web.config`, if you're changing custom errors you first have to remove the existing custom error, for example:

```
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="http://google.com" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

IIS7 is quite good and the clue is often in the error message:

> Cannot add **duplicate** collection
>   entry of type 'error' with combined
>   key attributes 'statusCode,
>   subStatusCode' respectively set to
>   '404, -1'

Comment: That makes sense.  I wonder why the error only hits where there are multiple worker processes.

Comment: @tim - were you trying to debug the app from VS at the time this happened?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was fixed by installing [c++ redistributable 2015 14.0.23026](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587)